# Line following challenge - robot moves forward but ignores the line

Tags: c++, robotics

I am trying to solve a line following challenge with a 3Pi+ robot, using 3 IR sensors (array in my code) and although I get my array working, receive the right data in the serial monitor and set a threshold value for my sensors, I cannot seem to make the robot follow the line : the robot moves forward but ignores the line.

I am adding my code here:

```
const int left_sensor_pin = A0;
const int right_sensor_pin = A3;
const int centre_sensor_pin = A2;

// store values into array
#define NB_LS_PINS 3
int ls_pin[NB_LS_PINS] = { left_sensor_pin, centre_sensor_pin, right_sensor_pin };
int which;

// store time
unsigned long start_time;
unsigned long elapsed_time [3];
unsigned long end_time_ls [3];
unsigned long set_motors;

bool done = false;

# define L_PWM_PIN 10
# define L_DIR_PIN 16
# define R_PWM_PIN 9
# define R_DIR_PIN 15

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode (left_sensor_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode (right_sensor_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode (centre_sensor_pin, INPUT);
  delay(5000);

  pinMode(L_PWM_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(L_DIR_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(R_PWM_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(R_DIR_PIN, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(L_DIR_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(R_DIR_PIN, LOW);

  analogWrite(L_PWM_PIN, 50);
  analogWrite(R_PWM_PIN, 50);
}

void loop() {

  //charge capacitor
  pinMode (left_sensor_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (right_sensor_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (centre_sensor_pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(left_sensor_pin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(right_sensor_pin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(centre_sensor_pin, HIGH);

  // Delay for capacitor to charge.
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  start_time = micros();

  pinMode (left_sensor_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode (right_sensor_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode (centre_sensor_pin, INPUT);

  bool pins_read [3] = {false, false, false};
  done = false;

  while ( done == false ) {

    for ( int which = 0; which < NB_LS_PINS; which++) {

      if ( digitalRead (ls_pin[ which ]) == LOW && pins_read [which] == false) { // need also to track whether pins are read, a single = is setting to a value and == compares values

        end_time_ls [which] = micros ();
        elapsed_time [which] = micros() - start_time;
        pins_read [which] = true;
      }

      if (pins_read [0] == true && pins_read [1] == true && pins_read [2] == true) {

        done = true;
      }
    }
  }

  elapsed_time[0] = end_time_ls [0] - start_time;
  elapsed_time[1] = end_time_ls [1] - start_time;
  elapsed_time[2] = end_time_ls [2] - start_time;

  Serial.println (elapsed_time [0]);
  Serial.println (elapsed_time [1]);
  Serial.println (elapsed_time [2]);
  Serial.println("------------------------------");

  //Motors

  if (elapsed_time [0] < 10000 && elapsed_time[1] > 10000 && elapsed_time[2]  < 10000)
  {
    //go forward
    analogWrite( L_PWM_PIN, 100 );
    analogWrite( R_PWM_PIN, 100 );
  }

  else if (elapsed_time [0] > 10000 && elapsed_time[1] < 10000 && elapsed_time[2]  < 10000)
  {
    // Turn right.
    analogWrite( L_PWM_PIN, 100 );
    analogWrite( R_PWM_PIN, 0 );
  }
  else if (elapsed_time [0] < 10000 && elapsed_time[1] < 10000 && elapsed_time[2]  > 10000)
  {
    // turn left.
    analogWrite( L_PWM_PIN, 0 );
    analogWrite( R_PWM_PIN, 100 );
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is on the last part where you have a triple condition separated with && yet you don't have an else condition and you don't cover all possibilities of these 3 statements with if/elseif. Because of this the go forward that is set at first might just stay the same forever, unless you enter one of the other 2 else ifs. Don't have the hardware so can't test for sure but might be worth adding an else here and checking which of these forward/right/left you are covering during runtime

Comment: Thank you ! I will try add an "else"to cover more. I was also wondering if adding a threshold was the right think to do or if I should add something like this instead:                   ``` unsigned long left_sensor_value = digitalRead (left_sensor_pin);
  unsigned long centre_sensor_value = digitalRead (centre_sensor_pin);
  unsigned long right_sensor_value = digitalRead (right_sensor_pin);

  if (left_sensor_value == LOW && centre_sensor_value == HIGH && right_sensor_value == LOW)
  //go forward
    analogWrite( L_PWM_PIN, 100 );
    analogWrite( R_PWM_PIN, 100 ); ```

Comment: This depends on precision and preference. Servos will never turn exactly the same on fixed time due to power or physical difference, but it makes it easier to code and if error is small enough to ignore go for it. Because even though turning a certain angle is more precise, it requires extra gyro sensors or some sort of other method to define identify where you are facing. final note: make sure to check what happens if one of those are exactly equal to 10000 somehow. seems like you are ignoring it on all elseif branches from the look of it.

Comment: True, I may need to use =><, I've been adjusting the threshold value and adding more conditions and my robot is starting to make jerky moves ! But do you know how to write intervals in Arduino ? I would like to write something like if  20000<sensorsX<30000 then ... but I cannot find this info on  C++ websites